# Plots lists of data after assagn then in a function

Tags: r

I started using R for a course of Computational Fluid Dynamics and one of the starting lessons we should create a function that put out two lists of data. So I wrote this function:

```
Green.Ampt=function(param){
    k=param[1]
    Psi=param[2]
    DTheta=param[3]
    h=param[4]
    F1=0.65
    F1=0.65
    vector.F2<-1:h
    vector.f<-1:h 
    for(tempo in 1 : h){
        DeltaF=1
        while(DeltaF>0.01) {
            F2=k*tempo+Psi*DTheta*log(F1/(Psi*DTheta)+1)
            DeltaF=abs(F1-F2)
            F1=F2
        }
        vector.F2[tempo]=F2
        vector.f[tempo]= k*(Psi*DTheta/F2+1)}
    OUT<-list(vector.F2, vector.f)
    return(OUT)
}
```

I used this `Green.Ampt(c(0.65,16.7,0.34,10))` to run the function then I controlled the console have recieved the following output:

```
[[1]]
[1]  3.152985  4.745484  6.077012  7.284812  8.404389  9.469498
[7] 10.490538 11.474561 12.434380 13.371189`

[[2]]
[1] 1.8205417 1.4277289 1.2573215 1.1566294 1.0891396 1.0397461
[7] 1.0018123 0.9716419 0.9468141 0.9260188`
```

I want to give at this two series of data a name because I need to plot them, but I am not successful in this.

Comment: mylist = myfunction(c(x,y)); names(mylist) = c("part.1", "part2")

Answer (score 0):

Save the return value of your function as an object, which in this case will be a list. You can then extract the components of the list using `[[` notation in a call to `plot`:

```
x <- Green.Ampt(c(0.65,16.7,0.34,10))
plot(x[[1]], x[[2]])
```

Here's the result:

[image]